# Telegram : Service worker is disabled

Tags: telegram

I'm a new user of Telegram. After creating my account, Telegram found my contacts, with their mobile number, and I had an answer to the first message I sent.
A new contact gave me only a code like @abcdefg. I found him, but the messages are not sent.
I get the message "Service worker is disabled. Streaming media may not be supported.Try reloading the page without holding  key.
Reloaded, but no result.
What can be the problem ... and the solution ?

I have no idea what to try.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to the web version of Telegram on web.telegram.org. I don't know what causes this but I recently got the same problem. I tried disabling all my extensions and filters and still got the problem.

My solution was switching to "K Mode" in the Telegram Settings. The K version is also available at https://web.telegram.org/k/ and the Z version is available at https://web.telegram.org/z/.

Comment: Thanks, but finally, I switched to Google chat.